# Pass variables to Click event

Tags: c#, button, parameters, click

I have following code for creating dynamic buttons but message box allways shows 8. How would I make it show in example 4 when I click `button[0][4]`? I have tried labda and delegate but both allways return 8 (`text[i].Count`). The same things happen to variable `i`.
It must be something very simple but I can't find it :-(.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++) // text.Count is 3
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < text[i].Count; a++) // text[i].Count is 8
        {
            button[i][a].Location = new Point(230, 30 +22 *a);
            button[i][a].Text = "Done" + i + " " + a;
            button[i][a].Click += delegate { click(a); };
...

private void click(int a)
{
    MessageBox.Show("" +a);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're capturing the loop variable inside the closure.
When the event fires, that variable is always equal to the last item.

Instead, you need to declare separate variables inside the loop, so each each lambda will capture its own variable that never changes.

Comment: Wasn't this "breaking change" happening sometime soon ... ? Where the variable is inside the loop?

Comment: I'm not sure, but in this particular case he is using an int, not a reference type. So it looks like everything is going to be ok

Comment: @SLaks do you mean to say declaring `int newVariable = a` and `delegate { click(newVariable);};` would solve this problem? I agree it is going to pick up the last value but I am not so sure declaring a new variable will solve this... I think this would need a different solution.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: No; this was only changed for reference types.

Comment: @BharathramAttiyannan: Wrong; a variable declared inside a loop will create a separate closure per iteration.  In Javascript, this would not work.

Comment: @SLaks Ah, I missed the delegate part.

Answer (score 2):

Since SLaks hasn't yet given an example.. I will. Here is a small re-creation of your issue:

```
internal class Test
{
    public EventHandler Click;
}
```

..then main method:

```
var list = new List<Test>();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    Test t = new Test();
    t.Click += delegate
    {
        click(a);
    };

    list.Add(t);
}

foreach (var t in list)
{
    t.Click(null, null); // 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
}
```

You need to create a local variable inside the loop, so each closure gets its own copy:

```
var list = new List<Test>();

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    int a = i; /* <--------------- THIS LINE HERE ------------------ */
    Test t = new Test();
    t.Click += delegate
    {
        click(a); // use the new variable here
    };

    list.Add(t);
}

foreach (var t in list)
{
    t.Click(null, null); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```

Which produces the correct output.